# H1 title stuck behind border on expand

Tags: html, css

Hey all you awesome people, Im looking to make a title `<h1>` to show in front of the `.imageHolder` img tag. At the moment, it sits behind `.imageHolder` border. `.imageHolder` expands on hover then the title is stuck behind border.

I have tried setting the `z-index` property and it dosen't seem to work. Any ideas would be appreciated as well as any options on shortening code etc.

```js
//Mouseover/out function for Image Slider Div
$(function() {
  $('.imageSlider')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').addClass('transition');
      $(this).addClass('transition');
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').removeClass('transition');
      $(this).removeClass('transition');
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
    });
});
//Mouseover/out function for Next button on Image Slider
$(function() {
  $('.btnNext')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').addClass('transition');
      $(this).addClass('transition');
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').removeClass('transition');
      $(this).removeClass('transition');
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
    });
});
//Mouseover/out function for Back button on Image Slider
$(function() {
  $('.btnBack')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').addClass('transition');
      $(this).addClass('transition');
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').removeClass('transition');
      $(this).removeClass('transition');
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
    });
});
//Variables Used for holding/releasing Images
var nextDelay;
var backDelay;
valueArray = 0
Images = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.png"]

//Delay on swapping Image after click/Gets Next Image In Array

function Next() {

  nextDelay = setTimeout(getNext, 1400);
  $('.imageHolder').fadeTo(1200, 0, 'linear');

}

function getNext() {
    $('.imageHolder').fadeTo(20, 1, 'linear');
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHolder')[0];
    valueArray = valueArray + 1;
    if (valueArray > 2)
      valueArray = 0;
    image.src = Images[valueArray];
  }
  //Delay on swapping Image after click/Gets Last Image In Array

function Back() {
  backDelay = setTimeout(getLast, 700);
}

function getLast() {
  var image = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHolder')[0];
  valueArray = valueArray - 1;
  if (valueArray < 0)
    valueArray = 2;
  image.src = Images[valueArray];
}
```

```css
body {
  /*Sets page background-colour*/
  width: 100%;
  /*Sets page width*/
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #404040;
}
.transition {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
.imageSlider > .imageHolder {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border: 10px solid #021a40;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: white;
}
.imageSlider {
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 350px;
}
.btnNext {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 60px;
  outline: none;
  /*Stops border appearing after user click*/
}
.btnBack {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 60px;
  outline: none;
  /*Stops border appearing after user click*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Main Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="zoom.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Courses.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="imageSlider">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img class="imageHolder" onclick="changeImage()" src="a.jpg">
    <input class="btnNext" type="image" src="btnNext.png" onclick="Next()" alt="Next Image" />
    <input class="btnBack" type="image" src="btnBack.png" onclick="Back()" alt="Last Image" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dont worry about the onclick property. Currently it is void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `h1` style to this:

```
h1{
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-left:5px;
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2000;
}
```

In order for the `z-index` to work, you need to apply the `position` attribute as well. Setting the `position` to `relative` will not move the `H1` tag on the page, but allows `z-index` to work.

Here is a sample:

```js
//Mouseover/out function for Image Slider Div
$(function() {
  $('.imageSlider')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').addClass('transition');
      $(this).addClass('transition');
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').removeClass('transition');
      $(this).removeClass('transition');
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
    });
});
//Mouseover/out function for Next button on Image Slider
$(function() {
  $('.btnNext')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').addClass('transition');
      $(this).addClass('transition');
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').removeClass('transition');
      $(this).removeClass('transition');
      $('.btnNext').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
    });
});
//Mouseover/out function for Back button on Image Slider
$(function() {
  $('.btnBack')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').addClass('transition');
      $(this).addClass('transition');
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeIn(00);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.imageHolder').removeClass('transition');
      $(this).removeClass('transition');
      $('.btnBack').stop(true, true).fadeOut(00);
    });
});
//Variables Used for holding/releasing Images
var nextDelay;
var backDelay;
valueArray = 0
Images = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.png"]

//Delay on swapping Image after click/Gets Next Image In Array

function Next() {

  nextDelay = setTimeout(getNext, 1400);
  $('.imageHolder').fadeTo(1200, 0, 'linear');

}

function getNext() {
    $('.imageHolder').fadeTo(20, 1, 'linear');
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHolder')[0];
    valueArray = valueArray + 1;
    if (valueArray > 2)
      valueArray = 0;
    image.src = Images[valueArray];
  }
  //Delay on swapping Image after click/Gets Last Image In Array

function Back() {
  backDelay = setTimeout(getLast, 700);
}

function getLast() {
  var image = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHolder')[0];
  valueArray = valueArray - 1;
  if (valueArray < 0)
    valueArray = 2;
  image.src = Images[valueArray];
}
```

```css
body {
  /*Sets page background-colour*/
  width: 100%;
  /*Sets page width*/
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #404040;
}
.transition {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
.imageSlider > .imageHolder {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border: 10px solid #021a40;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: white;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2000;
}
.imageSlider {
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 350px;
}
.btnNext {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 60px;
  outline: none;
  /*Stops border appearing after user click*/
}
.btnBack {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 60px;
  outline: none;
  /*Stops border appearing after user click*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Main Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="zoom.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Courses.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="imageSlider">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img class="imageHolder" onclick="changeImage()" src="a.jpg">
    <input class="btnNext" type="image" src="btnNext.png" onclick="Next()" alt="Next Image" />
    <input class="btnBack" type="image" src="btnBack.png" onclick="Back()" alt="Last Image" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice one, that fixed it. <Learning everyday :}>